# Spring Authentication not working as expected

Tags: spring, jsf, oauth, spring-security

I have a page (relevant previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086914/best-way-to-implement-social-oauth-with-facebook) where I need the user to be authenticated using the classic username-password and with his social account.

Here is some code:

```
Index.xhtml

<h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false" style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <p:growl id="growl" sticky="false" life="3000" showDetail="false" />
        <p:focus for="j_username"/>

        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Please Login
            </f:facet>

            <p:watermark for="j_username" value="username@isp.com"/>                            
            <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel value="Email" for="j_username" />
                <p:inputText id="j_username" value="#{loginBean.userName}" 
                             required="true" label="Email" requiredMessage="Email is required"
                             validatorMessage="Please use a valid email address">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="j_username"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Password" for="j_password"/>
                <p:password id="j_password" value="#{loginBean.password}" feedback="false"
                            required="true" label="Password" requiredMessage="Password is required"
                            validatorMessage="Password must be at least 7 characters" />
                <p:message for="j_password"/>                                

                <h:outputText value=""/>
                <p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.doLogin()}" value="Login" ajax="false"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
 ....`enter code here`
 <h:form> 
      <h:commandLink id="facebook" action="#{loginBean.doFBLogin}" > 
          <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/fb-login.png" /> 
      </h:commandLink> 
 </h:form>
```

Backing bean

```
LoginBean.java::doLogin()


public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException {
  LOG.debug("**** Executing doLogin method of LoginBean...");
  ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext();

  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
        .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + userName
                + "&j_password=" + new String(password));

  // Forwards to original destination or to error page
  dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
        (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

  // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
  return null;
}




public String doSocialAuthorization(String userName, char[] pass) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.debug("**** Executing doLogin method for user coming from OAuth authentication");
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext();
        String passS = new String(pass);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + userName
                        + "&j_password=" + passS);

        // Forwards to original destination or to error page
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        LOG.debug("**** User authenticated through facebook finished");
        return null;
    }
```

`LoginBean.java::doFBLogin()`  is called when the user selects auth with his facebook account. `Method doFBLogin()` calls the library `scrib`- java for the details and finally the system gets the email from user and creates a record in the Database. Then it triggers `doSocialAuthorization()`. 
This fails for some reason. The strange part is after the creation I enter the data in the form manually, classic way, everything works fine! The user gets access!

Comment: Why do you call the `j_spring_security_check` endpoint with username and password in your `doSocialAuthorization` method? Where does that password come from? You shouldn't have any password from the user, if he uses OAuth.

Comment: i create a dummy password. I think that for spring security to work, it needs a password to be present for each user in DB. Am i wrong?